# Tkinter GUI window items are really messy

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I created a garbled mess of code for a GUI that displays items (tarot cards) in a window in rows and columns. However, after creating more than four items, the items shift to the right leaving a large black empty space, beyond that I want the buttons for draw card and quit to be on the sides of the title, and make the entire thing generally just look a bit cleaner. If anyone could shed some light or provide suggestions I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

[image: Window resizing issue]
Window resizing issue

[image: Ideal layout]
Ideal layout

Also please note, I am brand new to Tkinter, I apologize in advance

```py
def draw_one_card_command():
    card = draw_card()
    if card:
        card_name = f"Card: {card}"
        card_meaning = f"Meaning: {CARD_MEANINGS.get(card.name, 'Meaning not available')}"
        try:
            img = Image.open(CARD_IMAGES[card.name])
            if card.reversed:
                img = img.rotate(180)
            img = img.resize((100, 175))
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            card_label = ttk.Label(cards_frame.interior, text=card_name + "\n" + card_meaning, image=img, compound="top")
            card_label.image = img
            cards_frame.cards.append(card_label)
            row = len(cards_frame.cards) // 5
            column = len(cards_frame.cards) % 5
            card_label.grid(row=row, column=column, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            card_label = ttk.Label(cards_frame.interior, text=card_name + "\n" + card_meaning)
            card_label.grid(sticky="w", padx=5, pady=5)

def on_configure(event):
    cards_frame.canvas.configure(scrollregion=cards_frame.canvas.bbox("all"))

def on_title_configure(event):
    title_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

root = Tk()
root.title("PyTarot")
root.geometry("800x600")

# Define custom styles
root.tk_setPalette(background="black", foreground="purple")
root.style = ttk.Style(root)
root.style.configure("TFrame", background="black")  # Set frame background color to black
root.style.configure("TLabel", foreground="purple")  # Set label text color to purple
root.style.configure("TButton", foreground="purple")  # Set button text color to purple

frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.grid(sticky="ew")

title_label = ttk.Label(frm, text="~ ~ ~ PyTarot ~ ~ ~", font=("Helvetica", 16, "bold"))
title_label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, sticky="ew")

draw_button = ttk.Button(frm, text="Draw a Card", command=draw_one_card_command)
draw_button.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

quit_button = ttk.Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
quit_button.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

cards_frame = Frame(root, bg="black")
cards_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="nsew")

cards_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
cards_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

cards_frame.canvas = Canvas(cards_frame, bg="black", highlightthickness=0)
cards_frame.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

cards_frame.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(cards_frame, orient="vertical", command=cards_frame.canvas.yview)
cards_frame.scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
cards_frame.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=cards_frame.scrollbar.set)

cards_frame.interior = Frame(cards_frame, bg="black")
cards_frame.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=cards_frame.interior, anchor="nw")

cards_frame.interior.bind("<Configure>", on_configure)

cards_frame.cards = []

root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.bind("<Configure>", on_title_configure)

root.mainloop()
```

Tried resizing with
`root.geometry("800x600")`

Tried altering `row = len(cards_frame.cards) // 5` and `column = len(cards_frame.cards) % 5`

But the blank space persists regardless

Tried editing different variables within:

`draw_button = ttk.Button(frm, text="Draw a Card", command=draw_one_card_command) draw_button.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")`

and

`quit_button = ttk.Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy) quit_button.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")`

not much changed, and what did change was not what I intended

Comment: Calculate the row and column before appending the card to the list.

Comment: Create `cards_frame.interior` as child of `cards_frame.canvas` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 both of these changes seemed to have helped in making the rows fill up with 5 columns on each row, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest to use `Text` widget for showing those tarot cards, then you don't need to calculate the row and column values because of wrapping feature of `Text` widget.

For the buttons and label alignment issue in the top frame, you can use `.pack()` on the two frames `frm` and `cards_frame` and don't need to bind `<Configure>` event on the root window to move the `title_label`.

Below is the modified code:

```py
def draw_one_card_command():
    card = draw_card()
    if card:
        card_name = f"Card: {card}"
        card_meaning = f"Meaning: {CARD_MEANINGS.get(card.name, 'Meaning not available')}"
        try:
            img = Image.open(CARD_IMAGES[card.name])
            if card.reversed:
                img = img.rotate(180)
            img = img.resize((100, 175))
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            card_label = ttk.Label(cards_frame.container, text=card_name + "\n" + card_meaning, image=img, compound="top")
            card_label.image = img
        except FileNotFoundError:
            card_label = ttk.Label(cards_frame.container, text=card_name + "\n" + card_meaning)

        ### insert the card into the text widget
        cards_frame.container.window_create("end", window=card_label, padx=5, pady=5)
        cards_frame.cards.append(card_label)

root = Tk()
root.title("PyTarot")
root.geometry("800x600")

# Define custom styles
root.tk_setPalette(background="black", foreground="purple")
root.style = ttk.Style(root)
root.style.configure("TFrame", background="black")  # Set frame background color to black
root.style.configure("TLabel", foreground="purple")  # Set label text color to purple
root.style.configure("TButton", foreground="purple")  # Set button text color to purple

frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frm.pack()  ### use pack() to pack the frame at the top side

draw_button = ttk.Button(frm, text="Draw a Card", command=draw_one_card_command)
draw_button.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

title_label = ttk.Label(frm, text="~ ~ ~ PyTarot ~ ~ ~", font=("Helvetica", 16, "bold"))
title_label.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=10, sticky="ew")

quit_button = ttk.Button(frm, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
quit_button.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="ew")

cards_frame = Frame(root, bg="black")
cards_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)  ### used pack()

### use Text widget for showing the cards
cards_frame.container = Text(cards_frame, width=1, height=1, bd=0)
cards_frame.container.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=1)

cards_frame.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(cards_frame, orient="vertical", command=cards_frame.container.yview)
cards_frame.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

cards_frame.cards = []

root.mainloop()
```